# AWS Athena - How to convert string column to date? (column includes null)

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

How would I use the Athena Query editor to convert a column of string type to a date type. I am trying to use the date_parse(string, format) but I'm having the following issue when I try the following:

```
SELECT title, email, id, status, (date_parse(issue_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
FROM "database"."table"
```

I get the following error:

```
INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: ""
```

I understand that this is because my date column contains a nulls. How would I deal with this. If I try to do the following - it returns nothing:

```
SELECT title, email, id, status, (date_parse(issue_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
FROM "database"."table"
WHERE issue_date != NULL
```

Is there an easier way to do this? Or am I missing something?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint:  `is not null`.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`NULL` in databases does not work like in programming languages, which creates all sorts of surprising results. To check if something is `NULL`, it's better to use `… IS NOT NULL`, e.g. `issue_date IS NOT NULL`.

`NULL` in SQL is really not equal to anything else, and therefore also not not equal to anything else. As the [Wikipedia article about SQL `NULL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) says "SQL null is a state, not a value".

Comment: Solved that issue thanks to you! next I get this: `INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "1/6/2020 21:04" is malformed at "/6/2020 21:04"`- so I'm guessing it's having trouble with parsing. I played around with the parsing but can't seem to get it right

Comment: Looks like the date you are trying to parse does not follow the format you specify (you say dates are formatted as `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s`, but the error says your dates are actually in another format, I think it's `%e/%c/%Y %H:%i`).

Comment: Ugh I probably missed that. Dealing with different tables with different formats. Thanks! 

Is there a way to deal with a column that has dates in both formats: `%Y-%m-%d` and `%e/%c/%Y %H:%i`
Dealing with a dirty data set. Wondering if that's not possible to deal with at all or they need to be the same format?

Comment: I voted down this answer simply because it doesn't answer the OP's original question.  Instead you discuss and hint at how the OP might be able to use NULL and IS NOT NULL.  I'd be happy to change my downvote to an upvote if you can supply a complete answer the addresses the OP's question.  For example, can you include a full example of the OP's original select statement, modified with your IS NOT NULL suggestion, so that the string containing the date (or missing/null dates) are properly converted?